# How to add project baseline cost in Project server 2013 web app site?

Tags: ms-project-server-2013

I have installed MS Project server 2013 and integrated with SharePoint 2013
I created project web app site, and created Enterprise projects
When I click on my project and select task cost view
the baseline cost is grayed out and can not be entered can anyone tell me
how can I add baseline cost in project task cost view

Answer (score 1):

You can only edit few fields for project tasks in the web interface (PWA). to edit the Baseline 0 Cost, you need to edit the project in Project Pro 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Baseline 0 - 10 can be set from PWA using menu TASK > Set Baseline > (choose your baseline).